# Getting a Runtime overflow error but all variables are same type and have values in

Tags: excel, vba

[image][image]It's been a while since i have had to ask for help...my VBA coding skills are coming along but I am stuck on why I get a runtime error 6 Overflow issue on this codes with the lines

```
SalePriceVAT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(SalePrice - (SalePrice / TaxRateSale), 2)
CostPriceVAT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(CostPriceGross - (CostPriceGross / TaxRateCost), 2)
NettVAT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(SalePriceVAT - CostPriceVAT, 2)
```

all the values are Dim Currency and when I debug have values in....

If I try on error resume next I just get a zero on the SalePriceVat field... am sure this is something simple - I have tried looking for the solution...

Here's the full code

```
Option Explicit
Sub CalcBEandROIandMaxCostPrices()
Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Create B/Even and ROI Price"
'===================================================
'Worksheets and Tables
'
Dim Ws_DfltVals As Worksheet
Dim Ws_AmzDta As Worksheet
Dim Ws_Amzfees As Worksheet
Dim Tbl_AmzDta As ListObject
Dim Tbl_AmzFees As ListObject
'===================================================
'Last Row Variables
'
Dim Lastrow_AmzDta As Long
Dim Lastrow_AmzFees As Long
'===================================================
'Loop Variables
'
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long

'===================================================
'Number Variables
'
Dim Updaterow As Range
Dim Row As Long
Dim BaseFeePerCent As Currency
Dim AdditionalFeeLimit As Currency
Dim AdditionalFeePerCent As Currency
Dim Closingfee As Currency
Dim SellerFeeBase As Currency
Dim TotalFees As Currency
Dim SalePrice As Currency
Dim CostPriceGross As Currency
Dim CostPriceNett As Currency
Dim CostPriceVAT As Currency
Dim SalePriceGross As Currency
Dim SalePriceNett As Currency
Dim SalePriceVAT As Currency
Dim NettVAT As Currency
Dim Profit As Currency
Dim ROIProfit As Currency
Dim ROIPerCent As Currency
Dim TaxRateCost As Double
Dim TaxRateSale As Double
Dim FBAFee As Currency
Dim FBMCost As Currency
Dim PrepFeeNett As Currency
Dim ReferralFee As Currency
Dim PreviousProfit As Currency
Dim ROIAmount As Currency
Dim BreakEvenPrice As Currency
'===================================================
'String Variables
'
Dim Cat As String
Dim Locale As String
Dim Lkup As String
Dim FeeType As String
Dim refcalc As String
Dim ROIType As String
'===================================================
'
'Set Table Names
Set Ws_DfltVals = Sheets("CONFIG - Default Values")
ROIType = Ws_DfltVals.Range("b2")
ROIPerCent = Ws_DfltVals.Range("c2")
ROIProfit = Ws_DfltVals.Range("d2")

Set Ws_AmzDta = Sheets("DATA - Amazon Data")
With Ws_AmzDta
Set Tbl_AmzDta = Ws_AmzDta.ListObjects("AmazonDataTable")
End With
'
Set Ws_Amzfees = Sheets("CONFIG - Amazon Fees")
With Ws_Amzfees
Set Tbl_AmzFees = Ws_Amzfees.ListObjects("AmazonFeesTable")
End With
'===================================================
'Unprotect Worksheets
Ws_AmzDta.Unprotect
Ws_Amzfees.Unprotect
'===================================================
'Get Last Rows
'
Lastrow_AmzDta = Tbl_AmzDta.Range.Rows(Tbl_AmzDta.Range.Rows.count).Row
Lastrow_AmzFees = Tbl_AmzFees.Range.Rows(Tbl_AmzFees.Range.Rows.count).Row
'
'Convert Amazon Fee Key To Values
Ws_Amzfees.Activate
With Ws_Amzfees
Ws_Amzfees.Range("c2:c" & Lastrow_AmzFees).Value = Ws_Amzfees.Range("c2:c" & Lastrow_AmzFees).Value
End With

'
'===================================================
'Process Amazon Data File
'
Ws_AmzDta.Activate
a = 2
b = 1

'
For a = 2 To Lastrow_AmzDta
Application.StatusBar = "Calculation BEven & Target ROI Prices " & a & " of " & Lastrow_AmzDta
'
'Set Variables
'
TaxRateCost = 1 + Ws_AmzDta.Range("bt" & a)
TaxRateSale = 1 + Ws_AmzDta.Range("bd" & a)
CostPriceGross = WorksheetFunction.Round(Ws_AmzDta.Range("bm" & a), 2)
CostPriceNett = WorksheetFunction.Round(CostPriceGross / TaxRateCost, 2)
FBAFee = WorksheetFunction.Round(Ws_AmzDta.Range("t" & a), 3)
PrepFeeNett = WorksheetFunction.Round(Ws_AmzDta.Range("bu" & a) / TaxRateCost, 2)
Cat = Ws_AmzDta.Range("e" & a)
Locale = Ws_AmzDta.Range("ad" & a)
FBMCost = Ws_AmzDta.Range("cq" & a)
'
'============================================================
'Calculate Intial Costings and Profit/Loss
'
'Get Referal Fee For Category
Lkup = Locale & "-" & Cat
With Ws_Amzfees
Set Updaterow = Ws_Amzfees.Range("C2:C" & Lastrow_AmzFees).Find(Lkup)
End With
If Updaterow Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Configuration Error - Amazon Fee not set for " & Lkup & " Asins Not Processess for this Category")
    Debug.Print Lkup
    GoTo Nextrec
End If
'
Row = Updaterow.Row
BaseFeePerCent = Ws_Amzfees.Range("d" & Row) / 100
AdditionalFeeLimit = Ws_Amzfees.Range("e" & Row)
AdditionalFeePerCent = Ws_Amzfees.Range("f" & Row) / 100
Closingfee = Ws_Amzfees.Range("g" & Row)
FeeType = Ws_Amzfees.Range("h" & Row)
'============================================================
'
'Loop Profit Calculation Until Profit less than or Equal Zero
'
For b = 1 To 100

If b = 1 Then
    SalePrice = 0
    PreviousProfit = 0
End If

SalePrice = SalePrice - PreviousProfit

'
'Check For Lower Cost FBA Fee
If b <> 1 Then
If SalePrice <= 10 Then
FBAFee = WorksheetFunction.Round(Ws_AmzDta.Range("el" & a), 3)
End If
End If
'
'Referall Fee Calculation
'
If b <> 1 Then
If FeeType = "Total" Then
    If AdditionalFeePerCent = 0 Then
        SellerFeeBase = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(SalePrice * BaseFeePerCent, 3)
    End If
    If AdditionalFeeLimit <> 0 Then
        If SalePrice > AdditionalFeeLimit Then
            SellerFeeBase = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(SalePrice * AdditionalFeePerCent, 3)
        End If
    End If
    If AdditionalFeeLimit <> 0 Then
        If SalePrice <= AdditionalFeeLimit Then
            SellerFeeBase = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(SalePrice * BaseFeePerCent, 3)
        End If
    End If
End If
'
If FeeType = "Portion" Then
    If SalePrice > AdditionalFeeLimit Then
        SellerFeeBase = SalePrice * AdditionalFeePerCent
   End If
    If SalePrice <= AdditionalFeeLimit Then
        SellerFeeBase = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(SalePrice * BaseFeePerCent, 3)
    End If
End If
ReferralFee = SellerFeeBase + Closingfee

End If
'
'Calcualte TotalCost & Profit
'
SalePriceVAT = SalePrice - (SalePrice / TaxRateSale)
CostPriceVAT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(CostPriceGross - (CostPriceGross / TaxRateCost), 2)
NettVAT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(SalePriceVAT - CostPriceVAT, 2)
'
TotalFees = WorksheetFunction.Round(CostPriceGross + SalePrice + PrepFeeNett + FBAFee, 2)

'
Profit = WorksheetFunction.Round(SalePrice - CostPriceGross - PrepFeeNett - FBAFee - ReferralFee - NettVAT - FBMCost, 2)
PreviousProfit = Profit
Debug.Print "BEVEN Calc " & b
Debug.Print "Cost Price = " & CostPriceGross
Debug.Print "Sales Price = " & SalePrice
Debug.Print "Prep Fee = " & PrepFeeNett
Debug.Print "FBA Fee = " & FBAFee; ""
Debug.Print "Referral Fee = " & ReferralFee; ""
Debug.Print "Nett Vatt = "; NettVAT
Debug.Print "Profit = " & Profit
Debug.Print " ========================="
'
'OnceProfit is Less than or Equal to Zero Exit Loop
'
On Error Resume Next

If Profit = 0 Then
Ws_AmzDta.Range("cf" & a) = SalePrice
BreakEvenPrice = SalePrice
b = 101
Else
    If SalePrice = -1 Then
        SalePrice = SalePrice * -1
    End If
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Next b
'============================================================
'
'Calculate Target ROI Price
'
If ROIType = "ROI" Then
ROIAmount = (CostPriceGross * (1 + ROIPerCent))
ROIAmount = ROIAmount - CostPriceGross
Else
ROIAmount = ROIProfit
End If
'
SalePrice = BreakEvenPrice + ROIAmount









Nextrec:
Next a

'===================================================
'Convert Amazon Fee Key Back to Formula
Ws_Amzfees.Activate
With Ws_Amzfees
.Range("c2:c" & Lastrow_AmzFees).Formula = "=CONCAT([@Market],""-"",[@Category])"
End With
'===================================================
'Protect Worksheets
Ws_Amzfees.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Some sample data would also prove useful - not an image, put some data into your post

Comment: As I am unable to reproduce the problem then it must be the actual data that is the issue - debug to find which values are causing the issue. "Trying" on error resume next is NOT debugging - it's also a very foolish thing to do. Rare are the occasions you need that particular syntax

Comment: Thanks I am aware of the issues with on error resume next and was just testing it...The spreadsheet is quite large... shall I just copy the one sheet?

Comment: I think I may have found the issue....Saleprice has 0 so it is trting to divide by 0 when there should be a value in.... if this is the case I will delete this! Appreciate you pointing me in right direction

Comment: the 0 value was causing one error but I still cannot work out the problem. the line CostPriceVAT = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(CostPriceGross - (CostPriceGross / TaxRateCost), 3) is erroring - these are values from debug befroe the calce..TaxRateSale = 1.2
TaxRateCost= 1.2
CostPriceGross = 20.5

I will add the data to the main post too...

Comment: @CHill60 i cannot see any option to attach sample data to the question?

Comment: been testing further and issue seems to be linked to the TAXRATESALE and TAXRATECOST variables - when I remove from calculation it works....

Comment: do you have errors in the cells or could your numbers be stored as text?

Comment: no all are numbers - I just changed the order of a calc and it seems to work .... I was assuming that where the code stopped was the error but the change i made was before the line i thought was giving the error..